# How to find out the nearest Whole number to a decimal after multiplying it with powers of 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have a float number `7.999999985666533` which is nearest to 8 and I have used it using `math.isclose`

```
math.isclose(a, b)
```

but for float values like `1.5999999991220535` the nearest integer is 2 but if I multiply it with `10 (10 ** 1)`, I get 16 as the closest integer which is also the result by `isclose`

Another example:

`1.2799999997163347` should give 128 after its multiplied by `100 (10 ** 2)`

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Why not just `round`? There are probably some edge cases, someone more pedantic will point them out for you.

Comment: why are you surprised at the results? `round` (or `isclose`) and multiplying by something just can't be interchanged (the operations do not commute)... ah, your real question is in the title, right?

Comment: @hiro protagonist Yes. To he clear 1.279999 when using round will give 1 but isclose of 1 and 1.279999 will he False

Comment: 'nearest whole number' , what do you mean by nearest , what is your tolerance for the nearest? `isclose` ,the default tolerance is 1e-09, which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What exactly is the input? Is is the float number and the exponent of 10, or is it just the float number? (In the latter case, the routine would need to find the appropriate power of ten.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuous fractions are quite powerful. Maybe it is a small overkill here, but it works.

```
import numpy as np

def get_cont_fraction(x, depth=0, maxdepth=10, precision=1e-6):
    if depth > maxdepth:
        out = []
    else:
        assert x >= 0
        out=[]
        if not depth:
            out += [ int(x) ] + get_cont_fraction( x - int( x ), depth=depth + 1, maxdepth=maxdepth, precision=precision)
        elif x < precision :
            out=[]
        else:
            out += [ int(1./ x) ] + get_cont_fraction(1. / x - int( 1. / x ), depth=depth + 1, maxdepth=maxdepth, precision=precision)
    return out

def get_fraction(inList):
    num = inList[-1]
    den = 1
    testList = inList[:-1:]
    testList = testList[::-1]
    for a in testList:
        num , den = a * num + den, num
    return ( num, den )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = get_fraction( get_cont_fraction( 1.5999999991220535  ) )
    print a
    print a[0]*1./a[1]
    a = get_fraction( get_cont_fraction( 1.2799999997163347  ) )
    print a
    print a[0]*1./a[1]
```

giving:

```
>> (8, 5)
>> 1.6
>> (32, 25)
>> 1.28
```

Comment: Works perfectly, although replacing `print(a[0] * 1. / a[1])` with `print(str(a[0] * 1. / a[1]).replace('.', ''))` gives the result i was looking for.

Comment: @gc7__ ok.nice. but if you want to avoid string manipulation you could use `print int( a[0] * 1. / a[1] * 10**( 1 + int( np.log10( a[1] ) ) ) )`

Comment: @gc7__ but if you are ok with string solutions, let me try another one.

Answer (score 2):

As solutions using string operations seem to be OK, here is a nice short one:

```
def nearest( x, Max9 = 2 ):
    s = str(x).replace('.','')
    splitter = Max9 * '9'
    sOut = s.split( splitter )[0]
    return int( sOut ) + 1

a = 7.999999985666533
b = 1.5999999991220535
c = 1.2799999997163347

print nearest( a )
print nearest( b )
print nearest( c )
```

just providing:

```
>> 8
>> 16
>> 128
```

**Edit**

As correctly pointed out by @gc7__ the above solution ignores cases of slightly bigger values. This makes the code a bit more complicated but is still quite ok.

```
import re

def nearest( x, Max09 = 2, digits=25 ):
    s = ('{val:.{dig}f}'.format( dig=digits, val=x ) ).split('.')
    rnd = 0
    if len(s) < 2 or s[1] == '0':## input is integer xyz or float of type xyz.
        out = int( x )
    else:
        s0, s9 = Max09*'0', Max09*'9'
        splitter = '{}|{}'.format( s0, s9)
        body = s[0]
        p0, p9 = s[1].find(s0), s[1].find(s9) ### returns -1 if nothing is found
        tail = re.split( splitter, s[1] )[0]
        out = int( body + tail )
        if p9 > -1 and ( p9 < p0 or p0 < 0 ):
            rnd = 1
    return out + rnd

a = 7.999998560066533
b = 1.5999999991220535
c = 1.2799999997163347
d = 1233
e = 19935
f = 1.6000000000123
g = 10006.6000000000123
h = 500001.0

print nearest( a )
print nearest( b )
print nearest( c )
print nearest( d )
print nearest( e )
print nearest( f )
print nearest( g )
print nearest( h )
```

providing:

```
>> 8
>> 16
>> 128
>> 1233
>> 19935
>> 16
>> 100066
>> 500001
```

Comment: but note: in this version `19935` would give `2`

Comment: Also another corner case, `1.6000000000123` will be `16` but it can be done using continuous `0s`. Thanks

Comment: Note, as you check for `p9 < p0` you can use the value of rnd to decide whether to split at `0`s or `9`s. Therefore, the import of `re` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

[`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) tells you if two `floats` are close given the parameters `rel_tol` and `abs_tol`. the default settings are

```
rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0
```

[`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) will just skip to the next integer wich may be far outside these tolerances.

setting `abs_tol` to something `<0.5` will make `isclose` `True` for something you have used `round` on:

```
from math import isclose

f = 1.5999999991220535
r = round(f)
print(r)                                  # 2
print(isclose(f, r))                      # False
print(isclose(f, r, abs_tol=0.5-0.00001)) # True
```